# vim syntax highlighting: remove the long underline

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I am using syntax highlighting scripts found from [here](http://www.fleiner.com/vim/download.html). I am using [java.vim](http://www.fleiner.com/vim/syntax_60/java.vim), [javacc.vim](http://www.fleiner.com/vim/syntax_60/javacc.vim), [html.vim](http://www.fleiner.com/vim/syntax_60/html.vim) and [c.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3064). But I am getting a long line under some keywords like this --

[image]

Moreover, those syntax highlighting scripts are saved in my `~/.vim/syntax` folder and I am not sure, if the vim is using them from the `.vim/syntax/` folder or from `/usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/`, how to fix it and how to force the vim to load the syntax highlighting scripts from `.vim/syntax/` folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the problems with the highlighting, try to reproduce without any other configuration and plugins, and then send feedback to the syntax plugin author. He's in the best position to fix this.

Unless you've messed up your `'runtimepath'`, scripts from `~/.vim` are preferred over the system-wide ones. Check

```
:set runtimepath?
```

In the output of `:scriptnames`, your user-local script should be sourced *before* the system-wide one. (The inclusion guard in each script ensures that the following scripts are not active.)